# Error while installing chrome extension through Python - selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to install chrome extension using Python Selenium.
When I click Add to chrome button a pop up(don't know whether it is a java scripted) is generated asking: "Add extension", "Cancel". I want to click "Add extension" but I am getting following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no alert open

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buyhatke/jaehkpjddfdgiiefcnhahapilbejohhj?hl=en")
time.sleep(15)
element=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.F-ia-k.S-ph.S-Rc-qa > div.h-F-f-k.F-f-k > div > div > div.e-f-o > div.h-e-f-Ra-c.e-f-oh-Md-zb-k > 
div.dd-Va.g-c-wb.g-eg-ua-Uc-c-za.g-c-Oc-td-jb-oa.g-c")
element.click()
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

help me to install it.

Updated code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import os

executable_path = "C:\\Users\\SACHIN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension("C:\\Users\\SACHIN\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\jaehkpjddfdgiiefcnhahapilbejohhj\\
3.4.143_0")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the download option pop up that you are trying to select using `switch_to.alert` is not actually a JS alert pop up. You can not select is using Selenium's `switch_to` methods. You need to use the `DesiredCapabilities` class to select this option and then use it in your code.

As per the ChromeDriver documentation, given [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions), please use the packed( the one with `.crx` extension ) or unpacked extension file (directory containing the extension, including a `manifest.json file`) and load it using `DesiredCapabilities`. This can be done using

```
     from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

     executable_path = "path_to_webdriver"
     os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

     chrome_options = Options()
     chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')

     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
     driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
     driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please help me where to find path to extension

Comment: path to extension is the path where you would download your `.crx` file. Suppose you're on a linux system, it could be /Users/Downloads or some directly

Comment: i am using windows 10

Comment: I managed to find path to extension. I am getting following error now ->Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SACHIN/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/stacktry.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\SACHIN\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\jaehkpjddfdgiiefcnhahapilbejohhj\\3.4.143_0'